# Упростить форматирование строки

Tags: python

Есть строка вида:

```
In [1]: p = '010203040506'
```

Форматирую:

```
In [2]:"{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}".format(p[:2],p[2:4],p[4:6],p[6:8],p[8:10],p[10:12])
```

Получаю результат:

```
Out[3]: '01:02:03:04:05:06'
```

Второй вариант:

```
':'.join([p[x:x+2] for x in xrange(0, len(p), 2)])
```

Есть еще варианты по упрощению форматирование строки?

Answer (score 4):

```
import wrap from textwrap

':'.join(wrap(p, 2))
```

А так можно много способов придумать:

```
':'.join(re.split('(\w{2})', p)[1::2])

':'.join('%02x' % ord(b) for b in binascii.unhexlify(p))

'%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x' % struct.unpack('BBBBBB', binascii.unhexlify(p))

# ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Смешно выглядит, но как вариант: `p.replace('0', ':0')[1:]`.

Comment: Не пойдет т.к. это mac-address в hex.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = list(p)

[lst.insert(3 * i + 2, ':') for i in range(5)]

''.join(lst)
```

---

*Результат:*

> ```
> '01:02:03:04:05:06'
> ```

---

*Объяснение команд:*

1. После создания списка символов из строки `p` …
2. … вставим двоеточие в каждую третью позицию (т.е. в позиции *2, 5, 8, 11, 14*) …
3. … и затем переводим таким образом модифицированный список обратно в строку.